# How to deal with ratelimit off booked project hours - Exact Online

Tags: python, api, get, rate-limiting, exact-online

My goal is to get the hours booked on projects for the years 2020-2021 from **Exact Online**. Currently, I am trying to get the right data with Postman and afterward I want to implement it in Python. I use the **project/TimeTransaction API**.

The API call I am doing:

> https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/<division_code>/project/TimeTransactions?$select=ID,Activity,ActivityDescription,Date,ProjectDescription,ProjectCode,Quantity,ModifierFullName,Modified,HourStatus,CreatorFullName,Attachment,ItemDescription,Type

Unfortunately, the GET request returns only the hours booked in 2013, 2014, and 2015. This is caused by the page size of 60 rows per call (you get only 60 records of data per request).

I tried to overcome this problem by making use of the skiptoken, for which the next value is given at the end of every request. The function of the skiptoken is to get the next 60 records of data. I have tried this multiple time but still I only receive the hours of 2013, 2014, and 2015. In addition, I used an `hourentryID` of `2021` as skiptoken (so what I would expect is to only get hours from 2021) but again only hours from 2013, 2014, and 2015.

The URL with skiptoken looks like this:

> https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/<division_code>/project/TimeTransactions?$select=ID,Activity,ActivityDescription,Date,ProjectDescription,ProjectCode,Quantity,ModifierFullName,Modified,HourStatus,CreatorFullName,Attachment,ItemDescription,Type&;$skiptoken=guid'1aa0ec3d-e40f-45e5-99de-03b04580c8e9'

Anyone familiar with this problem and able to help me?

Comment: The recommendation is to study the OData V3 specification. Their site odata.org is quite good and it helps you understand the concept. $skiptoken has nothing to do with filtering, for that there is $filter for instance. You might also want to look at existing pieces of code elsewhere on StackOverflow.

Comment: @guidoLeenders I don't get how OData would help me solve this problem?

Comment: It helps to understand the differences between skiptoken and OData-standard like filter.

Comment: @GuidoLeenders Thanks for your help, I indeed needed a filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Guido Leenders, you need a filter. The following example eliminates all time transactions with a `Date` prior to January 1, 2020.

```
$filter=Date ge DateTime'2020-01-01'
```

This would make the full URI:

```
https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/<division_code>/project/TimeTransactions?$select=ID,Activity,ActivityDescription,Date,ProjectDescription,ProjectCode,Quantity,ModifierFullName,Modified,HourStatus,CreatorFullName,Attachment,ItemDescription,Type&$filter=Date ge DateTime'2020-01-01'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the way to go and works.